# iOS 10+ using NSPersistentContainer - What's the best method to "clear all"

Tags: ios, core-data, ios10

We want to have a settings bundle property that can be set to delete all the information stored using core data.  I see some examples that loop over all the entities and calls delete.  I see some that manipulate the files storing the stores.  This last way sounds better but I'm not sure how that fits into the magic of NSPersistentContainer.

On iOS 10, what's the best way to delete all the content in Core Data and continue on in the app saving new fetched data to Core Data?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but here's what I think I'd do:

1. Create a new directory where you'll keep your persistent store and anything else that `NSPersistentContainer` wants to save. Make sure to create this directory when the app launches, using `FileManager`. You'll use this with Core Data by...
2. Subclassing `NSPersistentContainer` and overriding `defaultDirectoryURL()`. Use the directory from step 1.

Now you'll be sure that everything the persistent container writes goes in a known location that doesn't contain anything else.

When you want to delete everything, just delete every file in the directory that you're using (again, using `FileManager`). Make sure to do this **before** loading any data.